# Perl ord and chr working with unicode

Tags: perl, unicode

To my horror I've just found out that `chr` doesn't work with Unicode, although it does *something.* The man page is all but clear

> Returns the character represented by that NUMBER in the character set.  For example, chr(65)" is "A" in either ASCII or Unicode, and chr(0x263a) is a Unicode smiley face.

Indeed I can print a smiley using

```
perl -e 'print chr(0x263a)'
```

but things like `chr(0x00C0)` do not work. I see that my perl v5.10.1 is a bit ancient, but when I paste various strange letters in the source code, everything's fine.

<sup>I've tried funny things like `use utf8` and `use encoding 'utf8'`, I haven't tried funny things like `use v5.12` and `use feature 'unicode_strings'` as they don't work with my version, I was fooling around with `Encode::decode` to find out that I need no decoding as I have no byte array to decode. I've read much more documentation than ever before, and found quite a few interesting things but nothing helpful. It looks like a sort of the [Unicode Bug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#The-%22Unicode-Bug%22) but there's no usable solution given. Moreover I don't care about the whole string semantics, all I need is a trivial function.</sup>

So how can I convert a number into a string consisting of the single character corresponding with it, so that for example `real_chr(0xC0) eq 'À'` holds?

---

The first answer I've got explains quite everything about IO, but I still don't understand why

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use utf8;
use encoding 'utf8';

print chr(0x00C0) eq 'À' ? 'eq1' : 'ne1', " - ", chr(0x263a) eq '☺' ? 'eq1' : 'ne1', "\n";

print 'À' =~ /\w/ ? "match1" : "no_match1", " - ", chr(0x00C0) =~ /\w/ ? "match2" : "no_match2", "\n";
```

prints

```
ne1 - eq1
match1 - no_match2
```

It means that the manually entered `'À'` differs from `chr(0x00C0)`. Moreover, the former is a word constituent character (correct!) while the latter is not (but should be!).

Comment: @D.Shawley: Linux 2.6.32-42-generic, x86_64 GNU/Linux, Ubuntu 10.4, so utf8 is native

Comment: The UTF8 octet sequence for Á is `C3 81`  `C1` is the ISO-8859-1 code point.  My Perlfu is a little weak or I would propose an answer.

Comment: Some of the docs are weak in this regard, but the UTF-8 implementation, even in back Perl 5.10.1 is pretty strong. I'd recommend reading [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/perlunitut.html) and [perluniintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/perluniintro.html) before you go too far in working with Unicode in Perl. In your case, `chr` is not the problem, it's that you are not encoding and decoding your strings for UTF-8. If you're going to output UTF-8 (or any other encoding), your strings of characters need to be converted to octets on the way out first.

Comment: @ikegami: Removing it changes the output to `eq1 - eq1; match1 - no_match2`. So I have two equal strings with just one of them matching.

Comment: Unicode regex support in anything prior to Perl 5.14 is broken. In Perl 5.14, your second regular expression is fixed without `use encoding` and the `/u` modifier appended. See [Character set modifiers in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-set-modifiers)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First,

```
perl -le'print chr(0x263A);'
```

is buggy. Perl even tells you as much:

```
Wide character in print at -e line 1.
```

That doesn't qualify as "working". So while they differ in how fail to provide what you want, neither of the following gives you what you want:

```
perl -le'print chr(0x263A);'

perl -le'print chr(0x00C0);'
```

To properly output the UTF-8 encoding of those Unicode code points, you need to tell Perl to encoding the Unicode points with UTF-8.

```
$ perl -le'use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)"; print chr(0x263A);'
☺

$ perl -le'use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)"; print chr(0x00C0);'
À
```

---

Now on to the "why".

File handle can only transmit bytes, so unless you tell it otherwise, Perl file handles expect bytes. That means the string you provide to `print` cannot contain anything but bytes, or in other words, it cannot contain characters over 255. The output is exactly what you provide:

```
$ perl -e'print map chr, 0x00, 0x65, 0xC0, 0xF0' | od -t x1
0000000 00 65 c0 f0
0000004
```

This is useful. This is different then what you want, but that doesn't make it wrong. If you want something different, you just need to tell Perl what you want.

By adding an `:encoding` layer, the handle now expects a string of Unicode characters, or as I call it, "text". The layer tells Perl how to convert the text into bytes.

```
$ perl -e'
   use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
   print map chr, 0x00, 0x65, 0xC0, 0xF0, 0x263a;
' | od -t x1
0000000 00 65 c3 80 c3 b0 e2 98 ba
0000011
```

---

Your right that `chr` doesn't know or care about Unicode. Like `length`, `substr`, `ord` and `reverse`, `chr` implements a basic string function, not a Unicode function. That doesn't mean it can't be used to work with text string. As you've seen, the problem wasn't with `chr` but with what you did with the string after you built it.

A character is an element of a string, and a character is a number. That means a string is just a sequence of numbers. Whether you treat those numbers as Unicode code points (text), packed IP addresses or temperature measurements is entirely up to you and the functions to which you pass the strings.

Here are a few example of operators that do assign meaning to the strings they receive as operands:

- `m//` expects a string of Unicode code points.
- `connect` expects a sequence of bytes that represent a `sockaddr_in` structure.
- `print` with a handle without `:encoding` expect a sequence of bytes.
- `print` with a handle with `:encoding` expect a sequence of Unicode code points.
- etc

---

> So how can I convert a number into a string consisting of the single character corresponding with it, so that for example real_chr(0xC0) eq 'À' holds?

`chr(0xC0) eq 'À'` does hold. Did you remember to tell Perl you encoded your source code using UTF-8 by using `use utf8;`? If you didn't tell Perl, Perl actually sees a two-character string on the RHS.

---

Regarding the question you've added:

There are problems with the `encoding` pragma. I recommend against using it. Instead, use

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

That'll fix one of the problems. The other problem you are encountering is with

```
chr(0x00C0) =~ /\w/
```

It's a known bug that's intentionally left broken for backwards compatibility reasons. That is, unless you request a more recent version of the language as follows:

```
use 5.014;    # use 5.012; *might* suffice.
```

A workaround that works as far back as 5.8:

```
my $x = chr(0x00C0);
utf8::upgrade($x);
$x =~ /\w/
```

Comment: If you want a more manual solution, you can also `use Encode qw( encode ); print encode(chr(0x00c0))` which does pretty much the same thing as ":encoding(UTF-8)" above without an I/O handle.

Comment: @zostay, That should be `encode('UTF-8', chr(0x00c0))` or `encode_utf8(chr(0x00c0))`, but yeah.

Comment: @ikegami: You're surely right about the IO, but I don't care about IO, as it was just a debugging output. I'm not gonna output anything but ASCII, that's why I ignored the warning. I still don't understand what's going on, see my edit.

Comment: @maaartinus, Added answer to added question. Note that 5.14 is the oldest supported version of Perl.

Comment: @ikegami: That's it, with my version I can't do `use 5.014`, but  `utf8::upgrade` helped!